# How to redirect www to naked domain, with https redirect, in Nginx?

Tags: linux, nginx

My site is currently redirecting HTTP to HTTPS, however I'd like any request for www.example.com/page to redirect to example.com/page.

Ideally, I'd like for only one redirect to happen from http://www.example.com to https://example.com, instead of:
http://www.example.com 301 to https://www.example.com 301 to https://example.com

But I can live with a two redirects if necessary.

I've tried this and it didn't work:

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/example**

```
server { server_name www.exmaple.com; return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri; }
```

Here is the rest of the file:

```
server {
    server_name 165.62.38.252 example.com www.example.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/name/example-main;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/name/example-main/example.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Ce$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by $
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name 165.62.38.252 example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}

server { server_name www.example.com; return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri; }
```

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the last line from the configuration file

```
server { server_name www.example.com; return 301 $scheme://example.com$request_uri; }
```

Then check the configuration with "nginx -t" command and reload the configuration with "service nginx reload".

Comment: Thanks, I've removed the last line, and `nginx -t` returns `configuration file "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed"`. And I reloaded and `nginx -t` still says the same.

Comment: nevermind - the test was successful once I passed in sudo.

Comment: I've also tried this, which also doesn't work: `server {
    #listen 80 is default
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}


server {

    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name 165.22.38.251 example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}`

Comment: does it returns 404 when connecting to port 80 or it gives you the https redirect first?